# Shiny Presentation (ioslides): Custom CSS and logo

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, shiny, r-markdown

I have the following installed:

- preview release of RStudio, Version 0.98.864 (May 24th, 2014)
- development versions of knitr and shiny, via devtools::install_github(c("yihui/knitr", "rstudio/shiny"))

I would like to create a Shiny Presentation (RStudio menu items: File>New File>RMarkdow>Shiny>Shiny Presentation) with custom CSS but am unsure how to do so.

My custom CSS (which currently only changes the colour of header 2)

```
h2 { 
 font-size:1.8em; 
 color: red;
}
```

works with an extract of an example given on the [RMarkdown PResentations with ioslides webpage](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html):

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: temp.css
---

    ## Getting up

    - Turn off alarm
    - Get out of bed
```

However, when I convert this to produce Shiny output by including `runtime: Shiny`in the preamble, the custom formatting no longer works.

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
runtime: shiny
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: temp.css
---


## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## Slide with Interactive Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
          choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
          min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

Any tips on how to use a custom CSS with a Shiny presentation would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Similar to this problem, I have not been able to include my own logo by including the following in the front matter (obviously changing the png to one on my own system):

```
output:
   ioslides_presentation:
      logo: logo.png
```

nor do my ordered lists show a number 
Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. I think this is a bug, and please report to https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Yihui, I have reported this problem as suggested.

Comment: Did anyone find the answer to this question? `logo: logo.jpg` does not work. The error says data file logo.jpg not found.

Answer (score 2):

The [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/135) opened for the custom css support was closed Jun 24, 2014.

Testing with the original question text does indeed show the `h2` headings colored as stated in the css, also tested adding `logo: Rlogo-1.png` and indeed the logo is used.