# Error adding images and plots in ioslides_presentation w/ Runtime: shiny on Windows

Tags: shiny, rstudio, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

When I run the following `ioslides_presentation w/ runtime: shiny` at work (Windows 7 Enterprise)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "Thursday, February 05, 2015"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: images/rstudio-ball.png
runtime: shiny
---

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

I get an "invalid back reference" error when attempting to include a logo or plot into the presentation . However, if I remove `runtime: shiny` the presentation compiles as expected, with both the logo and the plot.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163147/shiny-presentation-ioslides-custom-css-and-logo-windows-7-8) for more specifics on the error.)

Comparing the list of compile instructions provided by RStudio I believe the error is caused by my employer's IT restrictions. Specifically, I've noted that when `runtime: shiny` is removed, the logo is pulled from

--variable "logo=images\rstudio-ball.png"

but when `runtime: shiny` is used, the logo is instead pulled from

-- variable
"logo=C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKa4VJH\file385c176c9bb_files/logo.png

If I go to the folder `C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKa4VJH\file385c176c9bb_files` the logo and any plots created in the presentation are indeed there but cannot be retrieved from this folder and included in the presentation.

**Question: How can I change the default folder RStudio uses to hold images prior to compiling the finished shiny presentation?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of the RMarkdown package are you using? Have you tried installing the latest one (i.e. `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")`? A few issues specifically related to ioslides + Shiny on Windows have been recently resolved.

Comment: @Jonathan - It appears that updating to **rmarkdown version 0.5.2** (currently the development version) fixes this issue.  If you want to post this as the answer, I'll check it off.  Thanks!